# Laravel, get nested array

Tags: php, laravel

So, this is my json format data

```
{
   "New Purchase Orders Created":{
      "date":"2018-02-26 14:05:14.000000",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"UTC"
   },
   "colour":"bg-primary"
}
```

This is my view in blade.php

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
         @foreach( $notifications as $notification )
                <?php $notificationData = json_decode($notification->data, true);?>
         @foreach( $notificationData as $key=>$item )
                <li class="list-group-item text-white {{ $notificationData['colour'] }}">
                  @if ($key!='colour')
                      {{ $key }}<br>  
                      {{ $item['date'] }}

                  @endif
                </li>
          @endforeach
          @endforeach
</ul>
```

I want to get the data into the blade. So what should I do?

[image]

This is what i want to get.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the notification title the key for the date?

Comment: @Phiter it's because this is notification view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_decode`. This works with JSON you've shown:

```
{{ json_decode($json, true)['New Purchase Orders Created']['date'] }}
```

If `New Purchase Orders Created` key may be different in every JSON, use the [`array_first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-first) helper:

```
{{ array_first(json_decode($json, true))['date'] }}
```

If you will have many elements, iterate over them:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
@foreach ($array as $key => $element)
    {{ $array[$key]['date'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: If not only just have the ['New Purchase Orders Created'], but ['Purchase Orders Arrived'] or somthing different can i still read? Or I have to change to using index? But how to use indexing?

Comment: @JweiWei if you'll use `array_first()` as I've shown, it doesn't matter what key the array has.

Comment: If now i got many and many data in, how should i get the second, third and fourth one?

Comment: @JweiWei iterate over the array with `foreach()`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Its output me an error "Illegal string offset 'date'"

Comment: still not working with the same error. so sorry, I'm newbie.

Comment: @JweiWei tried with the JSON you've given, works fine.

Comment: I think my problem is that the foreach loop 2 times, and the second array did not have the same element, so its ouput me and error?

Comment: {{ array_first(json_decode($notification->data, true))['date'] }}
This work fine for me, because it only loop the first array.
{{ (json_decode($notification->data, true))['date'] }}
But this give me an "Illegal string offset 'date'" error.

Comment: @JweiWei Why don't you check structure of data/object with `dd($dataOrNotificationOrWhatEverIsThere)` in controller itself before returning view?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the above JSON is an object array like this:

```
<?php
$notifications = '[{
   "New Purchase Orders Created":{
      "date":"2018-02-26 14:05:14.000000",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"UTC"
   },
   "colour":"bg-primary"
},
{
   "New Purchase Orders Created":{
      "date":"2018-02-26 14:05:14.000000",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"UTC"
   },
   "colour":"bg-primary"
}]';
?>
```

Thus, the script will be like this:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    @foreach( json_decode($notifications, true) as $notification => $data )
        <?php $item = $data[key($data)]; ?>
        <li class="list-group-item text-white {{ $data['colour'] }}">
            {{ key($data) }}<br>  
            {{ $item['date'] }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Undefined offset: 0. Error =(

Comment: I made changes to my answer, can you please verify?